# How To Say "When The Count Gets To This Number Execute This Function"?

Tags: swift, parse-platform

Before I reload a table I want to know that all of the tasks that were saving in the background are done saving. I have 5 different `saveInBackground` functions that must complete before I make a new `PFQuery`. My thought right now is to say:

```
object.saveInBackgroundWithBlock({ (Success: true, error) -> Void in

             count ++

            })
```

Then, once the count gets to a certain number to perform the query. I don't want to use `if` because if the network is taking too long to process the save request. Would a while statement work? Such as:

```
            while count < 0 {

                continue
            } else if count == 5 {

                self.fetchSecondaryObjects()

            }
```

Ideally I would be using a real-time data engine to power my application but I'm having trouble locating one that I can use as I only write in Swift. If this exists out there and you know of it, I'd love to know about it.

Answer (score 0):

Just do the check each time you increment. It's really very low overhead, only five comparisons.

```
object.saveInBackgroundWithBlock({ (Success: true, error) -> Void in
  count ++;
  if count == 5 {
    self.fetchSecondaryObjects()
  }
})
```

Unless I'm missing some reason you can't do that, it seems like the simplest solution. Better than running an infinite loop.

Comment: Your answer would certainly work. However, I'm not sure if this is the best way to do it. You are right, the overhead is low. But given that I can't know for sure which save will finish first, I would have to put that `if-statement` in each block. Therefore it would iterate 5 times. And really, not that it makes a huge difference, I need to have 8 `saveInBackgroundWithBlock` functions to finish before I call the query.

Comment: Well, maybe you could have each of the five `saveInBackground` functions call an `increment()` function that does both the incrementing, and the checking? That way it's only in one place in your code instead of 5. I agree that it's not exactly elegant, but in my opinion it beats the hell out of having a loop that may run indefinitely.

Answer (score -1):

Generally I try not to use while in such cases because one can easily get stuck in them if you're somehow of in your logic. Why don't you just use something like that:

```
if count >= xyz
```